# what is the difference between "some" == "some\0" and strcmp("some","some\0") in c++?

Tags: c++, string, comparison

what is the difference between  `"some" == "some\0"` and `strcmp("some","some\0")` in c++?

Why `if("some" == "some\0")` returns `false` and `if(!strcmp("some","some\0"))` returns `true` ?

Comment: because you can't compare `const char*` that way

Comment: The way this question is written is a little confusing due to int to boolean conversion, in the `strcmp` example.  You should check `strcmp(val1, val2) == 0` or `!= 0` to make it more obvious.

Comment: In **C++**, `(std::string("some") == std::string("some\0"))` is `true`. No need for `strcmp()` and its boundary issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the following diagram. It shows two strings in memory, their content is in the box, beside the box you'll see the address of each one.

[image: string content and addresses]

When you're doing `if("some" == "some\0")` you are comparing the addresses. It is translated into `if (0xdeadbeef == 0x0badcafe)` which is obviously false.

When you use `strcmp`, you compare the content of each box until you reach `\0` in each of them. That's why the second test returns true.

If you change the first test to `if("some" == "some")` then a compiler `may potentially` see that they are the same strings and will store them only once. Which means that your test will transform into `if (0x0badcafe == 0x0badcafe)` which is obviously true.

Comment: but if("some" == "some") is returning true

Answer (score 9):

```
"some" == "some\0"
```

compares the string literals by their addresses. These literals are **stored in different memory locations**. So always `false`.

```
!strcmp("some","some\0")
```

**compares the contents** of strings. Thus in that context `"some\0"` is same as `"some"`. So `true`.

**Edit**: From your comments you ask that why `"some" == "some"` is `true`. That's because mostly compiler are smart enough to reuse the string literal(when they are stored in **read only** region). That's why it returns `true`.

P.S. In below case "some" is not stored in read-only:

```
char a[] = "some";
```

Comment: "compares to string literals by their addresses". sorry for the silly question Can u elaborate it.?

Comment: `strcmp` compares two C string literals up to [i]the first null character[/i] ('\0') found (that's why "some" and "some\0" are considered equal by strcmp).

Comment: A string literal in c++ is of type `const char *`:  a pointer type.  If you compare them with ==, you're comparing the two pointers (or addresses).

Comment: Note the ! in front of his `!strcmp("some", "some\0")` and saying that it is always `true`.  I tried this for myself and this is in fact correct that `strcmp("some", "some\0")` returns `false`.

Comment: Another interesting point is that sometimes `"some" == "some"` will return true, but only because the string constant gets reused.

Comment: I disagree with "always false". `"some"` and `"some\0"` don't have to be stored in different memory locations, `{'s','o','m','e','\0','\0'}` works fine for both string constants because for the first it would be illegal for the program to access beyond the first terminator so it doesn't matter if there's a second '\0' or not.

Comment: @JonathonW The type of a string literal in C++ is **not** a pointer, but rather an array of character constants. As with all arrays they can be **implicitly converted** to a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `"some"` is `const char*`, so when you compare `"some"=="some\0"` you are comparing two `const char*` pointers. Since they may not point to same memory location the comparison would usually fail. In the second case, you are using `strcmp` which compares the strings by going through individual characters in the string.

Comment: but if("some" == "some") is returning true?

Comment: @Suri, that's because some compiler are smart enough to store same string literals in the same memory location. That's why @Naveen has mentioned word **usually**.

Comment: I think it might return true if compiler optimization is enabled. For example in VC9 there is a flag /GF (enable string pooling) which will create a single string (for read-only strings) if they are identical.

Comment: *"An ordinary string literal has type “array of n
const char”"* and they can be converted to a pointer type.