# If statement in my loops are being skipped in C

Tags: c

In function verify, I have a loop called "size" which is identical to the 3rd loop in "foodSelect" except that it works differently for some reason. It doesn't prompt me for input first, it goes straight to the if inside of it and asks `What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): Please enter S, M, or L only:`. It displays the error first, then prompts me again for input. It's weird.

Source (because it's long): http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KxrMAXaU

or source here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void menu();
void question (char choice[]);
void output(char *foodChoice, char *foodSelect, char *foodSize, int *foodOrderNum, float *foodSubtotal);
int verify(char *choice, char *foodChoice);

void menu() {
/*
printf("\n");
*/
    printf("\nWelcome to Sunny FISH & CHIPS!\n\n");
    printf("########     Fish :     Haddock(K) Large(L) | $5.00\n");
    printf("# FOOD #                Halibut(T) Large(L) | $4.00\n");
    printf("########     Chips:     Cut(C)     Large(L) | $2.00\n");
    printf("                        Ring(R)    Large(L) | $3.00\n");
    printf("                                            | \n");
    printf("##########   Soft Drinks(S)        Large(L) | $2.00\n");
    printf("# DRINKS #   Coffee(C)             Large(L) | $1.75\n");
    printf("##########   Tea(T)                Large(L) | $1.50\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Note: Medium price: 80%% of large.\n");
    printf("       Small price: 60%% of large.\n");
    printf("TAX is 10%%.\n");
    printf("More than 5 fish, 10%% discount on drink.\n");
    printf("Every 10 fish purchased, get 1 free softdrink.\n");
    printf("  - size of drink is according to size of fish\n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------\n\n");
}

int verify(char *choice, char *foodChoice) 
{
    int answer, rc = -1;
    if (choice == "order") 
    {
        do {
            answer = getchar();
            if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
            { rc = 1; }
            else if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n')
            { rc = 0; }
            if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
            {
                printf("Please enter y or n only: ");
                while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                answer = getchar();
            } 
        } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
    }
    if (choice == "foodSelect") 
    {
        do {
            answer = getchar();

                if (foodChoice == "Fish")
                {
                    do {
                        answer = getchar();
                        if (answer == 'K' || answer == 'k')
                        { rc = 1; }
                        else if (answer == 'T' || answer == 't')
                        { rc = 0; }
                        if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
                        {
                            printf("Please enter K or T only: ");
                            while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                            answer = getchar();
                        }
                    } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
                }
                if (foodChoice == "Chips")
                {
                    do {
                        answer = getchar();
                        if (answer == 'C' || answer == 'c')
                        { rc = 1; }
                        else if (answer == 'R' || answer == 'r')
                        { rc = 0; }
                        if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
                        {
                            printf("Please enter C or R only: ");
                            while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                            answer = getchar();
                        } 
                    } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
                }
                if (foodChoice == "Drinks")
                {
                    do {
                        answer = getchar();
                        if (answer == 'S' || answer == 's')
                        { rc = 1; }
                        else if (answer == 'C' || answer == 'c')
                        { rc = 2; }
                        else if (answer == 'T' || answer == 'T')
                        { rc = 3; }
                        if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
                        {
                            printf("Please enter S, C, or T only: ");
                            while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                            answer = getchar();
                        } 
                    } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
                }   
        } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
    }
    if (choice == "size") 
    {
        do {
            answer = getchar();
            if (answer == 'S' || answer == 's')
            { rc = 1; }
            else if (answer == 'M' || answer == 'm')
            { rc = 2; }
            else if (answer == 'L' || answer == 'l')
            { rc = 3; }
            if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
            {
                printf("Please enter S, M, or L only: ");
                while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                answer = getchar();
            } 
        } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
    }
}

void question (char *choice) {

    char *choiceYesNo;
    char *foodOptions;
    char *foodChoice;
    char *foodSelect;
    char *foodSize;
    int *foodOrderNum;
    float *foodSubtotal;

    switch (choice[0]) {
        case 'f':
            foodChoice = "Fish";
            foodOptions = "(K- Haddock, T- Halibut)";
            break;
        case 'c':
            foodChoice = "Chips";
            foodOptions = "(C- Cut, R- Ring)";
            break;
        case 'd':
            foodChoice = "Drinks";
            foodOptions = "(S- Softdrink, C- Coffee, T- Tea)";
            break;
    }

    printf("\nDo you order %s? (Y/N): ", foodChoice);
        verify("order", foodChoice);
    printf("%s choice %s: ", foodChoice, foodOptions);
        verify("foodSelect", foodChoice);
    printf("What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): ");
        verify("size", foodChoice);
    printf("How many orders do you want? (>=0): ");
        scanf("%d", &foodOrderNum);
    output(foodChoice, foodSelect, foodSize, foodOrderNum, foodSubtotal);
}

void output(char *foodChoice, char *foodSelect, char *foodSize, int *foodOrderNum, float *foodSubtotal) {

    printf("\nYou ordered %s: %c - SIZE: %c   amount ordered: %d, subtotal price: %.2lf\n\n", 
    foodChoice, foodSelect, foodSize, foodOrderNum, foodSubtotal);

}



int main() {

    //menu();

    question("drinks");


}
```

Comment: C doesn't support direct comparison of strings using `==`. Use [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) instead. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715247/what-is-the-difference-between-some-some-0-and-strcmpsome-some-0-in

Comment: Can you boil it down to a minimal testcase? That code is awfully long.

Comment: Hint: You can't use == to compare strings in C

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Look in `Verify`, e.g., `if (choice == "order")`, `if (foodChoice == "Drinks")`.

Comment: @antlersoft Then why does it work?

Comment: When you get a valid key, after you deal with it, reset `rc`.

Comment: @eveo -- It may appear to work sometimes.  When you use == on char *, you are comparing the pointers.  Since you assign a literal string and compare against a literal string, IF the compiler uses the same pointer for both literals, that will "work."  It's wrong in general for C strings, but when comparing with literals and assigning from literals, it MAY work, depending on your compiler.  However, this is mostly going to confuse you and make it hard for you to work with C strings until you understand what is going on with the difference between == on char * and strcmp().

Comment: @pmg That isn't the problem though. It skips my `answer=getchar();` and goes right to the if asking me to `Please enter S, M, or L only: ` and then only after the error does it prompt me to enter answer.

Comment: On another note, you have many repetitions of code to have the user enter one of a few options as input. Your code would be a lot simpler if you moved that into a function of its own, and just used it everywhere else, something like `get_input("KT");`, `get_input("YN");`, etc.

Comment: Nobody answered why my size loop is dysfunctional :(

Comment: Nobody answered that because you posted a gigantic wall of code. Post a small piece of code that illustrates the problem and you'll get somewhere. This is a poor question in need of improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you really shouldn't compare the strings with `==` (although in this case it is unfortunately not unlikely to work because you're only using string literals), your trouble is because the entry of choices needs the <kbd>return</kbd> key to be pressed. Thus when you obtain one character for the choice from the input buffer, there is still a newline left in it. Place a

```
printf("answer = %d\n",answer);
```

after the first `answer = getchar();` in the loop. That will tell you that you have gotten a newline `'\n'` (10) [or possibly a carriage return `'\r'` (13), but because of the following, I believe that's not the case] from the input buffer. In the `foodSelect` loop, you have an `answer = getchar();` before the if-statements, and one immediately at the beginning of the do-while loops, so that clears the input buffer. But in the `foodSize` branch you haven't.

After each choice, clear the input buffer

```
while((answer = getchar()) != -1 && answer != '\n);
```

Comment: Thank you, the part that got it working was the suggestion of putting `answer=getchar()` before my do while.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend the use of `getchar()` for interactive programs. You don't appear to handle the newline characters which are going to come in after everything you type. Use `fgets()` instead.

To clarify the above, when you press something like <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, you have entered *two* characters into standard input. The first call to `getchar()`, will return `'Y'`, and the next call will return `'\n'` (the newline character). Your code does not expect this following newline character and may appear to "skip" calls to `getchar()`, when really it is returning more characters you entered.

If you use `fgets()`, then you get the *entire* line that the user typed, including the newline, all at once. You (usually) won't have to worry about extra data waiting around in the input buffer.

Comment: Can't use fgets, only getchar. if (choice == "size") isn't my problem, that works fine, but that loop doesn't for whatever reason when it's practically identical to the 3rd loop in `foodSelect`.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to use `fgets()`? It's in `<stdio.h>`, same as `getchar()`, so there should be no problem.

Comment: If you can't use fgets for some awful requirement, you should read the '\n' directly on the scanf

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare strings with `==`.  As strings are essentially pointers (to an array of characters), you are comparing pointers (the actual addresses in memory where the characters are stored).  In order to compare the strings character-by-character, you need to use an appropriate function, the default choice being [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/).

Also, as Greg Hewgill mentioned, if you use `getchar`, you will get the skipping behavior described in your question.  The reason is that in order for the user to give control back to your code from getchar(), they need to press `enter` (this is how the console input works).  The key `enter` will be one of the characters read (i.e. the second if the user inputted "y"), so the comparison on the character will fail as well when `getchar` returns with the code for the `enter` key.

Comment: It turns out that the strings are assigned as constants and compared to constants, and if the OP's compiler does constant string folding (which seems to be the case), then `==` will actually work.

Comment: It might be, but that is compiler-dependent, the OP still should not rely on that behavior.  I missed the part on how he was calling `verify`, though