# C function skips if statements in do while loop and executes the last if only, but doesn't in second IDENTICAL function

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If statement in my loops are being skipped in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880665/if-statement-in-my-loops-are-being-skipped-in-c)

Having a weird problem. I have a program that I made where you can order drinks, chips, or fish. When you order anything, the second line is "what size do you want: (s small, m medium, l large)". Now, you can only enter `s, S, m, M, l, or L.` Anything beyond that, it enters the loop and tells you to enter only one of the above 6 characters.

In my verify function, I have 3 cases, one being if you have the following as the first parameter in verify: `foodSize, foodSelect, or order.`

Once in the verify function, and if the choice is `foodSize`, it goes into this loop:

```
if (choice == "foodSize") 
{
    do {
        answer = getchar();
        if (answer == 'S' || answer == 's')
        { rc = 0; }
        else if (answer == 'M' || answer == 'm')
        { rc = 1; }
                    else if (answer == 'L' || answer == 'l')
        { rc = 2; }
        if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
        {
            printf("Please enter S or M only: ");
            while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                answer = getchar();
        } 
    } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
}
```

I have the EXACT SAME CODE in foodSize as I do in the other two if's, just switching around the printf inside the 3rd if statement within the do while to `Please enter X or X only:` which doesn't affect anything. All the other loops work, regardless if I put them in different orders, or put it into `if, else if, and else`, or `if, else if, or else if`.

THE LOOP THAT HAS THE SAME CODE AND WORKS FINE (meaning it asks me for my input first, doesn't give me error message first):

```
            if (foodChoice == "Drinks")
            {
                do {
                    answer = getchar();
                    if (answer == 'S' || answer == 's')
                    { rc = 1; }
                    else if (answer == 'C' || answer == 'c')
                    { rc = 2; }
                    else if (answer == 'T' || answer == 'T')
                    { rc = 3; }
                    if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
                    {
                        printf("Please enter S, C, or T only: ");
                        while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                        answer = getchar();
                    } 
                } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
            }
```

Nothing works, nothing for foodSize work. Not even when I put `verify("foodSize", foodChoice)` FIRST in my question function:

part of my question function:

```
printf("\nDo you order %s? (Y/N): ", foodChoice);
    verify("order", foodChoice);
printf("%s choice %s: ", foodChoice, foodOptions);
    verify("foodSelect", foodChoice);
printf("What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): ");
    verify("foodSize", foodChoice);
```

If I put `verify("foodSize", foodChoice)` right after the first printf it doesn't change anything either.

**the output, no matter what, always skips my get char, gives me the error message first, then prompts me for input within my foodSize loop in my verify function REGARDLESS where the loop is placed, or what order it is in.**

**OUTPUT**:

`What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): Please enter S or M only:`

when instead it should be:

`What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small):`

I should only be prompted if I don't enter a lower case or upper case L, M, or S. Yet it prompts me regardless. I'm at wits and haven't been able to solve this yet. I know my code looks like shite, I know some of the ways I do things in it aren't the current standard way, but that's the way we have to do it in school, so please don't point out those errors. I just want to know why this loop isn't working and I want to fix it, that's all.

**FULL SOURCE** in case somebody wants to compile it and give it a run for themselves.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hjPDu4QB

Eternal great-fullness to whoever discovers why this does not work.

Comment: I do not have to use strcmp, because it works this way. I did it with `strcmp` as well, that didn't change anything, it still functioned the exact same way. If you read my post you would see: " I know my code looks like shite, I know some of the ways I do things in it aren't the current standard way, but that's the way we have to do it in school". Sorry, but that wasn't helpful at all.

Comment: Try printing `"foodSize"` and `choice` before the comparison: `printf("\"foodSize\" is at %p; choice is at %p\n", (void*)"foodSize", (void*)choice);`.

Comment: `foodSize is at 0x8048df8; choice is at 0x8048e23`

Comment: edit: my bad, here it is after the SIZE options has been run:

`Do you order Drinks? (Y/N): foodSize is at 0x8048df8; choice is at 0x8048e23  
Y  
Drinks choice (S- Softdrink, C- Coffee, T- Tea): foodSize is at 0x8048df8; choice is at 0x8048e44  
S  
What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): foodSize is at   0x8048df8; choice is at 0x8048df8   
Please enter S, M, or L only:  
`

Comment: The problem is I get `What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): Please enter S or M only:` instead of `What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small):`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr If `answer` is either `-1` (possibly `EOF`?) or `'\n'`, that expression will be `false`.

Comment: Of the 3 comparisons only 1 was true. When you compare `"foodSize"` and `choice` it's the pointers (the `0x8048e23`) that get compared, not their contents.

Comment: @Aaron: right.  Damn boolean mental breakdown...

Comment: @pmg well yeah that's what I want it to do, I want it to match one of the three cases. The problem is when it matches my foodSize case, it doesn't do the loop properly. Yet the code for that loop is the EXACT same code I have in another loop, which oddly enough, works fine. Why. Why does it do this.

Comment: String pointers are not meaningfully comparable by address.

Comment: Greg Hewgill's answer to your [original version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880665/if-statement-in-my-loops-are-being-skipped-in-c) is correct and is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Troubadour - I tried phrasing the question the best I could so I made a new thread since the old one is dead. I flagged it to be removed as well.

Comment: @eveo: The old question is not dead. It's been answered. Correctly.

Comment: Alright, I changed it to strcmp and instead of using getchar() I just did `scanf("%c", &answer);`. Still same problem.

Comment: @Troubadour Can you just not post anymore? It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Troubadour Moved my answer, voting to close as dup. eveo, Indeed, Greg Hewgill already pointed out the problem, as Troubadour said.

Comment: I solved it, I added `answer = getchar();` before the do while in foodSize and that fixed it. Great. I'm such a dick.

Comment: @DanielFischer Your answer about added the `answer = getchar();` before the do while fixed it. I don't know how to thank you, so I'm just going to say thank you. I can't believe something so simple fixed it.

Comment: Can you make it a separate post so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: eveo, you can accept it at your original question. I _could_ undelete it here, but that doesn't seem right, having voted to close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the line

```
if (choice == "foodSize")
```

is working at all, then you are depending on compiler optimizations.  What this is doing is comparing where in memory those two strings are located; if it is true, this is only because the compiler optimized them into two pointers to the same string.  The correct way to compare strings is with `strcmp`:

```
if(strcmp(choice, "foodSize") == 0)
```

This will actually compare the contents of the strings.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, and I specifically stated to not correct these things in my answer because it's EXACTLY what happened in my last thread and it didn't help in the slightest. I know I can do it this way. I know. Believe me, I know. It changes absolutely nothing. My program is still completely messed and with every passing second I am getting closer to a deadline which, if missed, will yield me a -30% of my course mark, destroying my GPA. I am at wits end. If you cannot help, please don't provide pseudo help. I just want to fix my program and get a good grade.

Comment: If you are so very certain that this comparison is valid, you are going to earn your failing grade.

Comment: But it actually is valid because I tried both ways and it goes in to the loop, but the loop is executed incorrectly both times. This is how we were taught. I know it's wrong, but if I do it differently, I'll get marks off. I don't make the rules.

Comment: @eveo: These things have to be corrected. It is not optional, period. Until you correct such obvious nonsensical errors in your code, there's no point in trying to do anything else.

Comment: The ONLY thing I want to know is how to fix the size loop so that it doesn't give me my error message, THEN prompts me for input.

Comment: @AndreyT No, wrong. I asked for help with a specific issue, and now everyone is piggy backing on another issue which may not be the correct way to do this, but it works.

Comment: @eveo, it may work sometimes, but this time around it obviously isn't working. If you do something knowingly wrong and the program still works, then you can say it doesn't matter. But in this case, it doesn't work and you CAN'T tell for sure this is not the culprit.

Comment: Alright, I changed it to strcmp and instead of using getchar() I just did `scanf("%c", &answer);`. Still same problem.

Comment: @eveo That `scanf` isn't eating the newline any more then your `getchar` was.  `scanf("%c\n", &answer);` will do it, but will choke if the input is just a newline.